# Como usar PyOpenGL

Tags: python, windows, opengl, pyopengl

Galera, gostaria de usar a biblioteca PyOpenGL em Python, porém eu estou tendo dificuldades para instalar. Gostaria de saber qual versão do OpenGL e do Python eu preciso baixar e instalar. Agradeço a ajuda desde já.

Comment: http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/installation.html

Comment: Você pode baixar o pyopenlg nesse [site](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOpenGL/3.0.2), como msi, exe, ou zip, depois você importa para o diretório do python onde você instalou.
Estou usando a versão 2.7; Aqui tem tutorias sobre [pyopengl.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDdfGpqjkEJSeWKGCP31__wD&v=R4n4NyDG2hI)

Comment: (adicionei a tag "windows" uma vez que nas várias distribuições de Linux, centenas de pacotes Python estão sempre prontos para serem instalados a partir da central de aplicativos, nas versões corretas. PyOpenGL inclusive - então essa é uma dificuldade apenas para usuários de Windows)